# Let $V$ be a vector space. If $U \leq V$, $Z \leq V$, $U \cap Z = 0$ and $Z \simeq V/U$, then $V = U \oplus Z$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space (possibly of infinite dimension).

I know that given a subspace $U$ of $V$, we can always write $V = U \oplus Z$, where $Z$ is some subspace of $V$ such that $Z \simeq V/U$.

Let $U$ and $Z$ be subspaces of $V$. I also know that, if $V = U \oplus Z$, then $Z \simeq V/U$.

Now I’m trying to prove the following statement: If $U \cap Z = 0$ and $Z \simeq V/U$, then $V = U \oplus Z$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true.

Assume $e_1,e_2,e_3,\dots $ is a basis for $V$, and let $U$ be spanned by $e_2,e_4,e_6,\dots$ and $Z$ by $e_3,e_5,e_7,\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is which map is giving you the isomorphism $Z\simeq V/U$. Let $\pi:V\to V/U$ denote the projection map.

Since [every short exact sequence of vector spaces splits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363198/short-exact-sequence-of-vector-spaces-splits-always/3363204), there is a map $i:V/U\to V$ such that its composition with the projection above $i\circ\pi=id_{V/U}$ is the identity map. This gives you a way to identify $V/U$ with the subspace $im(i)=Z$ of $V$, i.e., an isomorphism $i:V/U\to Z\subset V$ which yields $V= U\oplus Z$.

To detect a failure as in the example of the other answer you'd need to verify if the given isomorphism $f:Z\to V/U$ is compatible with the inclusion maps $j:Z\hookrightarrow V$ and $i: V/U\hookrightarrow V$: your claim holds if and only if $j=i\circ f$, i.e., both spaces are embedded as the same subspace of $V$.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective! I must say I don’t entirely get what you’re saying, mainly because it is my understanding that the map $i$ is not uniquely determined, so it is not clear to me what it means to check that $j = i \circ f$.

Comment: @Federico good catch! I'll fix my answer during the week to account for that mistake.  The whole point I'm trying to make is that a vector subspace is two pieces of information: "a vector space $Z$ and an embedding $i:Z\to V$". To make this precise we need to account for automorphisms of $Z$ and isomorphisms with other spaces. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject#as_classes_of_monomorphisms